# Terraform: What is this =>

Tags: terraform

Im new to Terraform. I am going through a tutorial and cant determine what this does " => "

Below is an example output utilizing this feature.

```
output "for_output_map2" {
  description = "For Loop with Map - Advanced"
  value = {for c, instance in aws_instance.myec2vm: c => instance.public_dns}
}
```

What is the name of this feature ?  What does it do ?  Thank you.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#result-types

Comment: I've noticed that all your questions got answered yet not a single answer was accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Answer (score 6):

This `=>` symbol is not a distinct operator in its own right, but rather just one of the delimiters for the parts of this overall [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html):

- `for` introduces the for expression, telling Terraform that this isn't just a normal object expression.
- `in` separates the symbol declarations from the source collection value.
- `:` separates the source collection value from the key expression.
- `=>` separates the key expression from the value expression.

`for` expressions can also have an `if` clause which follows the value expression, but there isn't one in the example you shared here. You can learn more about the `if` clause in [Filtering Elements](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#filtering-elements).

Comment: That was extremely helpful, I have my answer now.  Good day!!

Comment: @Nick_Scott If the answer was helpful, it should be accepted which marks your issue are resolved.

Answer (score 4):

"=>" is a separator for one key and value pair inside an object.

For example, given a source object:

```
source = {
    1: {name: "foo", id: 1212},
    2: {name: "bar", id: 5656}
}
```

After this expression:

```
output "sample" {
    value = {for k, v in source: k => v.name}
}
```

The **output** will be:

```
{1: "foo", 2: " bar"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the `=>` is kind of "map element separator" in Terraform. It is used to define key-value pairs within a map.
Using `=>` you  transform terraform map into another array or map for some purpose (e.g. using them for `for_each` Meta-Argument).

#### For example:

In snippet below, the `for_each` loop expression `"${employee.name}${employee.id}@gmail.com" => employee` is generating a map where the key is `"${employee.name}${employee.id}@gmail.com"` and the value is the `employee` object itself.

```
locals {
  # Array of Objects
  employees = [
    {
      name = "Alice"
      id   = 1234
      age  = 32
    },
    {
      name = "Bob"
      id   = 5678
      age  = 40
    }
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "emp_directory" {
  for_each =  { for employee in local.employees : "${employee.name}${employee.id}@gmail.com" => employee } 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo Email ID ${each.key} belongs to ${each.value.name}"
  }
}
```

Output will be a map of maps. Notice how the key and value is transformed:

```
{
  "Alice1234@gmail.com" = {
    "age" = 32
    "id" = 1234
    "name" = "Alice"
  }
  "Bob5678@gmail.com" = {
    "age" = 40
    "id" = 5678
    "name" = "Bob"
  }
}

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.emp_directory["Alice1234@gmail.com"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "emp_directory" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

  # null_resource.emp_directory["Bob5678@gmail.com"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "emp_directory" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }
```